# Custom Static Javascript HTML to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am trying to make invoices for my static website. I am trying to convert an `HTML` page to a PDF page. I been doing static websites rather than `Node.JS` because I can't host `Node.JS` websites. What have I done wrong?

**What have I tried**

invoices.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
      srcdoc="<p>Hello world!</p>"
      src="invoices.html"
      type="application/pdf"
    ></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Result**

I have gotten the "Hello World" to display but it was just in a html page rather then a PDF page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would better to create a small PHP script to handle this process.
Give a look at: spipu/html2pdf

A possible solution is to add a print button, something like this:

```
onclick="window.print();return false;
```

Then add this to the `<head>` tag:

```
type="text/css" media="print"
```

Comment: Well this would be on a separate page first. Second, would this work on static websites. I see you mention a Dyamic Library and I am not looking for any node.js libaries?

Comment: spipu/html2pdf is not node.js but is a php library.
Also onclick is pure js any browser support it.